# error on WP7 HttpWebRequest calling method

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, httpwebrequest

I am calling my method like HttpWebRequest and it will give me error like this
my code like this.

```
HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://url");
        objHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(r =>
        {
            WebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = objHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(r); //End Async Call to the URL
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) //get data in StreamReader
                {
                    string contents = reader.ReadToEnd(); //read content from reader and store it in content
                    XElement xmlResult = XElement.Parse(contents);
                    AEGAPI.clsGlobal.RandomToken = xmlResult.Value;
                }
```

[image: Error Snap]

My error report is

```
System.NotSupportedException occurred
  Message=Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Stream.get_WriteTimeout()
       at MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.get_Length()
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
       at AEGAPI.clsAEGAPI.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Authenticate>b__0(IAsyncResult r)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what kind of error do you have?

Comment: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.

Comment: ohh, I see. I had the trouble with the picture at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Would't it be simpler to use WebClient.DownloadStringAsync()?

```
void startDownload(Uri url)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += MyMethod;
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
}
void MyMethod(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var contents = e.Result;
    XElement xmlResult = XElement.Parse(contents);
    AEGAPI.clsGlobal.RandomToken = xmlResult.Value;
}
```

Comment: :- Thank you,for your reply can you help me bit more I am bit confuse on this request I am putting my whole code of retrieving data just you can correct my code then it would be the great help to me I am getting this problem at least 3 days so I can go ahead.

Comment: There's not much more to it than what I posted.  Please at least have a go before you ask for more help.